# How to set Azure Blob Storage storage lifecycle with Golang?

Tags: go, azure-sdk

I am trying to set storage lifecycle with azure-sdk-for-go unsuccessfully.
How can it be done using Golang?

Comment: Could you please provide your code?

Answer (score 1):

I first tried it with `AccountsClient` which only creates the account.
The solution was to use `ManagementPoliciesClient` which can be used for adding lifecycle rules, after the account was created.